# Is $a\sqrt[3]{2} + b\sqrt[3]{4}$ irrational?

Tags: radicals, irrational-numbers, rationality-testing

I need to prove that $$ a\sqrt[3]{2} + b\sqrt[3]{4}$$ is irrational, while $a$,$b $  are non zero  rationals.

I know that $\sqrt[3]{2} + \sqrt[3]{4}$ is irrational and I also know how to prove it, but I can't think of any reasonable implication that would state: $a\sqrt[3]{2} + b\sqrt[3]{4}$ is rational $\implies$ $\sqrt[3]{2} + \sqrt[3]{4}$ is rational, so I could show it is a contradiction.

Comment: It is not always irrational; consider $a = b = 0$.

Comment: Are their conditions imposed on the values of $a,b$ i.e.  are $a,b$ rational?

Comment: sorry...i corrected it

Comment: yeas a,b are rational

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890821/proof-that-sqrtma-sqrtnb-is-irrational.

Comment: Are you sure the given expression is rational? Consider $a=1,b=1$ and you get something irrational.

Comment: @Aniket I said exact opposite....

Comment: But you wrote something else in the first line of question and something different in the title.

Comment: my bad...corected

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829005/proving-that-sqrt3-2-sqrt3-4-1-are-linearly-independent-over-ration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $b\ne0$, then $a\sqrt[3]{2} + b\sqrt[3]{4}$ is rational iff $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is a root of a quadratic polynomial over $\mathbb Q$.

$\sqrt[3]{2}$ is a root of $X^3-2$, which is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$.

So, every polynomial having $\sqrt[3]{2}$ as root must be a multiple of $X^3-2$. In particular, $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is not a root of a quadratic polynomial over $\mathbb Q$.

Therefore, 
if $a\sqrt[3]{2} + b\sqrt[3]{4}$ is rational, then $b=0$.
But $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is irrational, and so $a=0$.

All this can be summarized as:

$1, \sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{4}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$ and so the only way that $a\sqrt[3]{2} + b\sqrt[3]{4}$ is rational is when $a=b=0$.

Comment: That is the thing...I need to prove that they really are linearly independent...thats why am trying to prove this.

Comment: Could you please explain it to me little further ?

Comment: thanks a lot....this helped

Answer (score 5):

Assume $a\sqrt[3]2+b\sqrt[3]4$ is rational. This gives that $$
(a\sqrt[3]2+b\sqrt[3]4)^2=2b^2\sqrt[3]2+a^2\sqrt[3]4+4ab
$$is also rational. Subtracting $4ab$ doesn't change rationality. This means that
$$
a(2b^2\sqrt[3]2+a^2\sqrt[3]4)-2b^2(a\sqrt[3]2+b\sqrt[3]4)=(a^3-2b^3)\sqrt[3]4
$$
is rational. But $\sqrt[3]4$ is irrational, so that can only be true if $a^3=2b^3$, which, under the assumption that $b\neq0$, implies that $\frac ab=\sqrt[3]2$ is rational. This is clearly a contradiction, and we are done.

Answer (score 2):

Set $\alpha=\sqrt[3]{2}$ and note that $\{1, \alpha, \alpha^{2} \}$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.You will contradict this if you proceed by contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $ a\sqrt[3]{2} + b\sqrt[3]{4}$ is rational, ($=y$, say)

So $ a\sqrt[3]{2} + b\sqrt[3]{4} = y$ and 
$ a\sqrt[3]{2} = y - b\sqrt[3]{4}$

Cubing both sides, we have 
$$ (a\sqrt[3]{2})^3 = (y - b\sqrt[3]{4})^3$$
$$ 2a^3=y^3-4b^3 + 3y\cdot 4^{\frac{2}{3}} - 3y^2\cdot 4^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

Equating rational and irrational parts, we have $$3y\cdot 4^{\frac{2}{3}} - 3y^2\cdot 4^{\frac{1}{3}}=0$$  or,
$$3y \cdot 4^{\frac{1}{3}}\left[4^{\frac{1}{3}} - y\right] = 0$$

Now our first assumption that $y$ is rational holds iff $y=0$

But then $\frac{a}{b}=-\frac{\sqrt[3]{4}}{\sqrt[3]{2}}$ implies $a,b$ irrational.

CONTRADICTION.