# Proving irrationality of $\sqrt[3]{3}+\sqrt[3]{9}$

Tags: number-theory, radicals, irrational-numbers

I need to prove $$\sqrt[3]{3}+\sqrt[3]{9}$$
is irrational, I assumed
$$\sqrt[3]{3}+\sqrt[3]{9} = \frac{m}{n}$$
I cubed both sides and got
$$\sqrt[3]{3}+\sqrt[3]{9} = \frac{m^3-12n^2}{9n^3}$$

I tried setting $$\frac{m^3-12n^2}{9n^3} = \frac{m}{n}$$ but that led me nowhere. so what can I do?

Comment: Please use *descriptive* titles. You have 150 characters to use, and you're more than welcomed to use $\rm\LaTeX$ as well. "Proving the irrationality of a number" is a meaningless title. Same goes to your other post from earlier.

Comment: Closely related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1542708

Comment: It may be that this exercise was intended to reinforce specific material covered in your textbook or other course materials, but your Readers will not be aware of that context unless you share it.  It is certainly a problem that is amenable to various attacks, so knowing what you are studying will help Readers respond in a way you find useful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let $\sqrt[3]3+\sqrt[3]9=r$.

Thus, since for all reals $a$, $b$ and $c$ we have:
 $$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc),$$ we obtain:
$$3+9-r^3+9r=0.$$

Now, let $r=\frac{m}{n},$ where $m$ and $n$ are naturals with $gcd=1.$

Thus, $$m^3-9n^2m-12n^3=0,$$ which says that $m$ is divisible by $3$.

Let $m=3m'$, where $m'$ is a natural number.

Thus, $$9m'^3-9n^2m'=4n^3,$$ which says that $n$ is divisible by $3$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: What did you set as a, b, and c?

Comment: @Guysudai1 They are any real numbers.

Comment: @Guysudai1 Michael seems to have chosen $a=\sqrt[3]{3}$, $b=\sqrt[3]{9}$, and $c=-r$. Then $a+b+c=0$ and one can study the left-hand side.

Answer (score 8):

Here are two other takes.

### Take 1

Let $\alpha = \sqrt[3]{3}+\sqrt[3]{9}$. Then $\alpha^3 = 9 \alpha + 12$.

By the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), if $\alpha$ is rational, then $\alpha$ is an integer.

Now $1 < \sqrt[3]{3} < 2 $ and $2 < \sqrt[3]{9} < 3 $, and so $3 < \alpha < 5$.

Since $x=4$ is not a root of $x^3 = 9 x + 12$, $\alpha$ is not an integer and so $\alpha$ is irrational.

### Take 2

We have $\alpha = \beta+\beta^2$, where $\beta=\sqrt[3]{3}$.

If $\alpha$ were rational, then $\beta$ would be a root of a quadratic polynomial with rational coefficients. However, the polynomial with rational coefficients with least degree having $\beta$ as a root is $x^3-3$.

Comment: It is fine what $\beta$ is a root of $x^3 - 3$ but how do you know that it is of least degree polynomial with rational coefficients. Are you using some standard result?

Comment: @prashantsharma, $x^3 - 3$ is a cubic with no rational roots and so is irreducible.

Comment: @Ihf Means are you suggesting that any equation with no rational roots is irreducible?

Comment: @prashantsharma, not any equation, but cubics, yes.

Comment: @Ihf Can you please supply a proof?

Comment: @prashantsharma, $f=gh$. What are the possible degrees of $g$ and $h$?

Comment: @Ihf The possible degrees of g,h are 1, 2. Since all the coefficients of f are rational so are of g, h otherwise we get a contradiction. Is this your argument?

Answer (score 5):

Let $a=\sqrt[3]{3}$ and $b=\sqrt[3]{9}$, and suppose that $a+b=r$ is rational. Then $$r^3 =(a+b)^3 = a^3+3ab(a+b)+b^3 = 12+9(a+b)=12+9r$$

So $r$ is a solution of equation $x^3-9x-12=0$ which has no rational root.